# DataGridView with BindingList<Outlook.MailItem> doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook, vsto

I am trying to bind a binding list to a datagrid, with autogeneratecolumns set to true. However no columns are showing and I am wondering why.

Code snippet:

```
datagridResults.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
List<MailItem> mailItems = new List<MailItem>();

//readPst() returns a List<MailItem> populated with MailItems from the specified PST.
mailItems = readPst(txtBoxPST.Text, "Archive Folders");
BindingList<MailItem> bl = new BindingList<MailItem>(mailItems);

datagridResults.DataSource = bl;
datagridResults.Refresh();
```

The datagrid ends up being blank. I am sure that the BindingList contains the MailItems, if I changed it from binding from the BindingList to a Foreach MailItem m in bl... manually adding the rows it works fine. So my best guess is that the AutoGenerateColumns doesn't work with the MailItem class? I am not sure why though, or the best way to work around it.

The MailItem class is the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>just add `ToList()` and don't need to refresh the `DataGridView`</s>

<s>datagridResults.DataSource = bl.Tolist();</s>

**Update**

This is how to read the `MailItems` in `OutLook`

```
public static void DisplayInbox(ApplicationClass o)
{
  // Get items in my inbox. 
  NameSpace outlookNS = o.GetNamespace("MAPI");
  MAPIFolder inboxFolder 
    = outlookNS.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
  // Print out some basic info. 
  Console.WriteLine("You have {0} e-mails.", 
    inboxFolder.Items.Count);
  Console.WriteLine();
  foreach(object obj in inboxFolder.Items)
  {
    MailItem item = obj as MailItem;
    if(item != null)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("-> Received: {0}", 
        item.ReceivedTime.ToString());
      Console.WriteLine("-> Sender: {0}", item.SenderName);
      Console.WriteLine("-> Subject: {0}", item.Subject);
      Console.WriteLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Source: [An Introduction to Programming Outlook 2003 Using C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289167%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work. I didn't think I needed the refresh, thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: @Jeremy Thompson, its true :). to Kiklion, i updated my answer. i hope it will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
BindingList<MailItem> mailItems
```

to

```
MailItem[] mailItems
```

i.e convert list to array
and try again

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps its a DataGridView property you've set. Try deleting the DataGridView on the Form and drag-drop a new one and only set its name Property. Then try this code that works:

```
public class MailItems
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}

List<MailItems> items = new List<MailItems>();
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    items.Add(new MailItems(){address = "1 Some St",name = "Kiklion"});
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    datagridResults.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    BindingList<MailItems> gridItems = new BindingList<MailItems>(items);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = gridItems;
}
```

Your code should work:

```
datagridResults.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
BindingList<MailItem> mailItems =  new BindingList<MailItems>(readPst(txtBoxPST.Text, "Archive Folders"));
datagridResults.DataSource = mailItems;
```

**Edit**

It wont work using a BindingList on the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem class. Instead of binding the DataGridView.Datasource directly to the Outlook Interop class I suggest you abstract the class as I've shown and update Outlook mail items with custom code.

Comment: I will edit the first question, that does work, but I am not using my own MailItems class, I am using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem class. Trying it with a new datagridview, without changing any option did not work as well.